# Nginx Reverse proxy to avoid legacy cyphers

Tags: nginx, encryption, reverse-proxy

I work for a company that has a legacy app that's using old ciphers on an old OS and one of the modules inside this app is a translation API that connects to api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com. I've been trying to create a reverse proxy to act as a middleman/reverse proxy between my web server 1 "10.10.10.11" and web server 2 "10.10.10.12" and the Microsoft site as they removed old legacy unsupported ciphers. we are doing our best to update/fix the issue but we need the module to be functional until we fix it. can someone help me with the configuration file?

what i tried is:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl/private_key_decrypted.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4';

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4';
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl/rootCA.crt;
        proxy_ssl_verify on;
    }
}
```

those certificates are created using OpenSSL on Ubuntu and installed in the ubuntu server, and I changed the site ip in webserver local host file to point to nginx server.
I appreciate any help you can provide.

the supported ciphers are:
Protocols
TLS 1.3 Yes
TLS 1.2 Yes

```
# TLS 1.3 (suites in server-preferred order)TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302) ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS 256TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303) ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS 256TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301) ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS 128
```

```
# TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f) ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS 128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030) ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS 256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8) ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS 256
```